# Fragment Tabs inside Fragment - Null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Inside my `MainActivity.java` I'm implementing a material design navigation fragment. 
When I tap on one of the navigation options, a new fragment appears - I want that fragment split into two separate fragments which can be switched via. Tabs.

I create the initially-shown one of those two fragments inside `MainActivity`:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
   // etc... 
   case 1: fragment = new OffersSentFragment();
}
```

Then make a simple `FragmentPagerAdaptor` (I've cut out the irrelevant code for this question):

```
public class OffersFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Offers Made", "Offers Received" };
    private Context context;

    public OffersFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0: return OffersSentFragment.newInstance("Sent");
            case 1: return OffersReceivedFragment.newInstance("Received");
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I make the two Fragments which will be tabbed between (`OffersSentFragment` and `OffersReceivedFragment`), both of which are basically the same at this point (one of which is shown below).

My problem is that the line:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new OffersFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity()));
```

in the `onCreateView()` method below causes a `java.lang.NullPointerException` - this method would usually work in an Activity ([this tutorial is similar to my code but uses an Activity instead](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)) but either `getFragmentManager()` or `getActivity()` seems to be probomatic in a fragment. What is causing this exactly?

```
public class OffersSentFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;  
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static OffersSentFragment newInstance(String param1) {
        OffersSentFragment fragment = new OffersSentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public OffersSentFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        // THE LINE BELOW IS THE NULL POINTER ERROR 
        viewPager.setAdapter(new OffersFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity()));

        SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers_made, container, false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue lies with the following line:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

Because you're trying to find the 'R.id.viewpager' in your activity. To do this, you would have to, in your activity, to call 'setContentView()' with an xml file that has a  in the xml.
My guess is that you don't have this?
Because that would mean your viewPager variable would be null, and that would cause the NullPointerException.

----- EDIT AFTER COMMENT -----

Then you need to find the 'R.id.viewpager' on the layout you're inflating, and not the activity's layout.
Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers_made, container, false);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new OffersFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity()));

    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}
```

This will find both the ViewPager and the SlidingTabLayout on the view you're inflating, which should work as you wanted.

Comment: My `R.id.viewpager` lies in the the `layout` file I am trying to return just after it - `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers_made, container, false);`. I am not sure if I have to duplicate this code in both fragments also to display the adaptor

Comment: Any way I can wrap the tab layout (`fragment_offers_made`) inside the rootView instead of returning the rootView like that? It causes me to have tabs inside tabs in my first fragment (as this code is implemented in the `onCreateView` of `OffersSendFragment`) - the second tab displays it's own layout as expected as I just return `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers_received, container, false);` in that one.